# Is this the best way to invoke on the fly in c#

Tags: c#

```
    // Something that might need to be invoked
    private void MightnInvoke()
    {
       // Invoke if we need to.
      if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke(new Action(this.MightnInvoke));

        // Do stuff here.             

    }
```

Is this the best way to invoke something on the fly in c#?

Basically i'm trying to avoid having extra code blocks where i don't need them.

or is it better to use synchronization context?

```
 public void SyncContext(object state)
        {
            try
            {
                int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Console.Writeline("Run thread: " + id);

                SynchronizationContext CommandContext = state as SynchronizationContext;

                   // Do stuff here and then use the CommandContext.
                    var Somestate = "Connected";
                    CommandContext.Send(Sometask, Somestate.ToString());              

                    Thread.Sleep(250);

            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException)
            {

            } 

  public void Sometask(object state)
        {
               // We can work in here and be on the same thread we came from.

            string Target = state as string;

            if (Target == "Connected")
            { }

        }
```

**UPDATE:**

Coming back to this, After profiling thread concurrency it turns out the method of sync context i gave as an example is indeed wrong. Don't use it useless you intend on changing it slightly to be thread safe.

Comment: put `this.Invoke(new Action(this.MightnInvoke));` inside the brackets or remove the curly brackets from above snippet.

Comment: What exactly are you saying? The syntax is correct as is.

Comment: Yes defenately it would compile but there is no meaning of braces there.

Comment: The braces were mostly for aesthetics, but i'll remove them.

Comment: The approach is correct. Did you check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired)? That at least prevents code duplication and implements a standard pattern for invoking methods on the UI thread

Comment: Interesting article, I just added another method i use that uses sync context. Just wondering what is best really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official MSDN docs for [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) it says;
`Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`.

Which would lead me to believe that your implementation may not be thread safe (though if it's working, then maybe I've mis-interpreted something).

Personally, it looks a little verbose for my liking.

I use the following in production and have never had an issue with threading.

```
public delegate void ActionCallback();
public static void AsyncUpdate(this Control ctrl, ActionCallback action)
{
    if (ctrl != null && (ctrl.IsHandleCreated && !ctrl.IsDisposed && !ctrl.Disposing))
    {
        if (!ctrl.IsHandleCreated)
            ctrl.CreateControl();

        AsyncInvoke(ctrl, action);
    }
}

private static void AsyncInvoke(Control ctrl, ActionCallback action)
{
    if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
        ctrl.BeginInvoke(action);
    else action();
}
```

Used as follows;

```
myTextBox.AsyncUpdate(() => myTextBox.Text = "Test");
```

Comment: if you catch `System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException` when you're "exiting" and ignore it, or run Enviroment.Exit(70); at the end of your exit method then it works "great".

Comment: Your method is much more efficient, Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, even if catching and ignoring does work, it's a good sign that the implementation isn't quite right. As you've mentioned, it seems more efficient to invoke and that seems to be the general consensus from the articles I've found on SynchronizationContext.